# thread with a forever loop with one inherently asynch operation

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, windows-services, service-broker

I'm trying to understand the semantics of async/await in an infinitely looping worker thread started inside a windows service. I'm a newbie at this so give me some leeway here, I'm trying to understand the concept.

The worker thread will loop forever (until the service is stopped) and it processes an external queue resource (in this case a SQL Server Service Broker queue).

The worker thread uses config data which could be changed while the service is running by receiving commands on the main service thread via some kind of IPC. Ideally the worker thread should process those config changes while waiting for the external queue messages to be received. Reading from service broker is inherently asynchronous, you literally issue a "waitfor receive" TSQL statement with a receive timeout.

But I don't quite understand the flow of control I'd need to use to do that.

Let's say I used a concurrentQueue to pass config change messages from the main thread to the worker thread. Then, if I did something like...

```
void ProcessBrokerMessages() {
   foreach (BrokerMessage m in ReadBrokerQueue()) {
      ProcessMessage(m);
   }
}

// ... inside the worker thread:
while (!serviceStopped) {
   foreach (configChange in configChangeConcurrentQueue) {
      processConfigChange(configChange);
   }
   ProcessBrokerMessages();
}
```

...then the foreach loop to process config changes and the broker processing function need to "take turns" to run. Specifically, the config-change-processing loop won't run while the potentially-long-running broker receive command is running.

My understanding is that simply turning the ProcessBrokerMessages() into an async method doesn't help me in this case (or I don't understand what will happen). To me, with my lack of understanding, the most intuitive interpretation seems to be that when I hit the async call it would go off and do its thing, and execution would continue with a restart of the outer while loop... but that would mean the loop would also execute the ProcessBrokerMessages() function over and over even though it's already running from the invocation in the previous loop, which I don't want.

As far as I know this is not what would happen, though I only "know" that because I've read something along those lines. I don't really understand it.

Arguably the existing flow of control (ie, without the async call) is OK... if config changes affect ProcessBrokerMessages() function (which they can) then the config can't be changed while the function is running anyway. But that seems like it's a point specific to this particular example. I can imagine a case where config changes are changing something else that the thread does, unrelated to the ProcessBrokerMessages() call.

Can someone improve my understanding here? What's the right way to have

- a block of code which loops over multiple statements
- where one (or some) but not all of those statements are asynchronous
- and the async operation should only ever be executing once at a time
- but execution should keep looping through the rest of the statements while the single instance of the async operation runs
- and the async method should be called again in the loop if the previous invocation has completed

It seems like I could use a BackgroundWorker to run the receive statement, which flips a flag when its job is done, but it also seems weird to me to create a thread specifically for processing the external resource and then, within that thread, create a BackgroundWorker to actually do that job.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`CancelationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx). Most async functions accept one as a parameter, and they cancel the call (the returned Task actually) if the token is signaled. [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204838(v=vs.110).aspx) (which you're likely using to issue the `WAITFOR RECEIVE` is no different. So:

- Have a cancellation token passed to the 'execution' thread.
- The settings monitor (the one responding to IPC) also has a reference to the token
- When a config change occurs, the monitoring makes the config change and then signals the token
- the execution thread aborts any pending WAITFOR (or any pending processing in the message processing loop actually, you should use the cancellation token *everywhere*). any transaction is aborted and rolled back
- restart the execution thread, with new cancellation token. It will use the new config

Comment: Thanks Remus, we can always depend on you when service broker is involved! :)

That's a good idea in itself but not quite what I'm looking for. I don't want to cancel the receive, I want the receive(s) to be able to keep running asynchronously while IPC calls are coming in and being "processed". The receive statement can pick up any changes relevant to itself (eg batch size or timeout) the next time it runs. 

I have a feeling I should consider a different control flow entirely here.

Answer (score 0):

So in this particular case I decided to go with a simpler shared state solution. This is of course a less sound solution in principle, but since there's not a lot of shared state involved, and since the overall application isn't very complicated, it seemed forgivable.

My implementation here is to use locking, but have writes to the config from the service main thread wrapped up in a Task.Run(). The reader doesn't bother with a Task since the reader is already in its own thread.